# Блок части приложения на время

Tags: android, android-studio

Как сделать блок приложения? Например, что бы какое-то активити блочилось после действия на 24часа и был установлен таймер обратного отсчёта?

Comment: сохраняете в `preferences` время начала блокирования и проверяете при запуске, прошло ли 24 часа

Comment: А потом юзверь чистит данные и продолжает пользоваться приложением. Без бэкенда тут никак